# gedit showing wrong strange numeric characters after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: upgrade, gedit, encoding, special-characters

I was running ubuntu 19.04, then I used the dist upgrade gui to upgrade to 19.10. Then I did the same to upgrade to 20.04, which I'm currently running.

I'm don't know if this started happening after the 19.10 upgrade or after the 20.04 upgrade but now my gedit is showing these strange numbered characters. If I just open gedit and start typing, this is what I see: [gedit strange chracters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZs9o.png)

I typed '123' on the first line and 'abc' on the second.

- The same thing happens if I paste text inside the editor.
- This doesn't happen with other text editors like LibreOffice Writer.

This is probably some simple configuration that got messed up with the upgrades but I don't know where to start.

Comment: You've probably installed a new font, or a new theme, or selected a foreign language or location, that's causing the problem. Switch back to the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@heynnema was right. The Gedit font got lost in the upgrade.

Font None selected on Gedit:

[image: Font None selected on Gedit]